# Getting Only Distinct Values Using Query in ArcGIS iOS

Tags: ios, arcgis-ios

Can any one Please tell me how can i Get only Distinct Values While Using Query and QueryTask in ArcGIS iOS SDK

This the Code i Write for Getting all the Names.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
   NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"My Server Url"];
   self.queryTask = [[AGSQueryTask alloc] initWithURL: url credential:cred];
   self.queryTask.delegate = self;

   self.query = [AGSQuery query];
   self.query.where = @"OBJECTID >= 1";
   self.query.outFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TYPE_EN", nil];
   [self.queryTask executeWithQuery:self.query] ;
 }  

- (void)queryTask:(AGSQueryTask *)queryTask operation:(NSOperation *)op didExecuteWithFeatureSetResult:(AGSFeatureSet *)featureSet
{
  self.featureSet = featureSet;
  NSLog(@"%@",self.featureSet.features);
  for (int i=0; i<[self.featureSet.features count]; i++)
  {
    AGSGraphic *feature = [self.featureSet.features objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *str = [feature attributeAsStringForKey:@"TYPE_EN"];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
  }
}

- (void) queryTask:(AGSQueryTask*)queryTask operation:(NSOperation*)op didFailRelationshipQueryWithError: (NSError*)    error
{
  NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
}
```

Now i am getting all TYPE_EN in 1000 fields Now i want to get only Distinct Values using Query How can i achieve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ios but you should be able to somehow attach the DISTINCT keyword as a prefix to your query. Perhaps self.query.prefix = "DISTINCT" ? Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I am not family with IOS, but you could always do like the comment and try to use DISTINCT in the query (assuming it stays along the SQL route).

However, one method I usually do is set up a List or Collection and store values there.  Before I store a value, I check to see if the List/Collection contains that value. If it doesn't, I add it.

That may be one way around setting up a complicated query.  I am not 100% sure what you're doing exactly with unique values though to give the best answer.